# Writing a System.Xml.XmlElement to a file on disk

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having trouble with writing a System.Xml.XmlElement to disk using C# .NET.

This is what I'm trying to do at the moment and failing:

```
XmlWriterSettings oSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
oSettings.Indent = true;
oSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
oSettings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\xmlfile.xml", oSettings);
System.Xml.XmlElement xml = sc.WFCFunctionCall();
xml.WriteContentTo(writer2);
```

the variable 'xml' definitely contains valid XML, I've stopped in the debugger and inspected.

```
xml.WriteTo(writer2)
```

also does not work.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Cheers!
Nick.

Comment: You say it's failing, but you haven't said in what way. What's happening? Note that ASCII isn't usually a great choice of encoding. Any reason you're not using UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Does not work" doesnt give us much to go on, but if I were to guess im thinking that you're inspecting the file right after the call to `xml.WriteTo(...)` and there is nothing there. You might try calling `Close` and/or `Dispose` on the XmlWriter.

Comment: This worked. I was using different XmlWriter objects for my different writes too so I thought they wouldn't interfere. Obviously they do! Thanks for your help on this!